# Issues booting Linux (Live ISO) - No screen, no keyboard / mouse, black screen,

Tags: system-installation

I have Windows 11 running on my machine, and I created a partition suitable for installing Linux on it.

I have downloaded the KDE Manjaro (Minimal) version and written it to a USB drive.
I can boot this ISO but I face issues with it:
For all the distributions I have tested, my monitor loses its signal (and thus displays 'No Signal' and switches, for example from DVI to HDMI-1). I need to press the physical button again in order to switch the input channel to the correct one.

For Manjaro, I can select to boot with either the Open Source or the Proprietary driver, and both of them boot into a KDE desktop environment to install, but my keyboard and mouse stop working - removing the cables and putting them in again doesn't seem to work).

Fedora for example just boots to a black screen and there's nothing I can do.

The only distro so far which I managed to install was Ubuntu (but also there I needed to change the monitor manually).

What could be the reason for this problem?
I've been struggling with this for a few days and I haven't found an answer.
Here are my main PC Specs:

- BaseBoard Manufacturer    ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
- BaseBoard Product PRIME X470-PRO
- BaseBoard Version Rev X.0x
- Processor AMD Ryzen 7 2700X Eight-Core Processor, 3700 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical
  Processor(s)
- BIOS Version/Date American Megatrends Inc. 4207, 07/12/2018
- SMBIOS Version    3.1
- BIOS Mode UEFI
- Adapter Type  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, NVIDIA compatible

I tried with fast boot enabled / disabled, secure boot disabled / enabled, but nothing seems to work. I hope to find an answer here.

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the BIOS to the latest available version, but all the issues reported above still remains.
Any ideas on other things I can try to be able to switch to Linux?

Comment: Try Fedora 35: https://mirrors.kernel.org/fedora/development/35/Everything/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Everything-netinst-x86_64-35-20210915.n.0.iso It's the only Linux that I'm aware of that contain kernel 5.14 out of the box. For some reasons you haven't specified your GPU which is the cornerstone here. Everything else is of almost no essence.

Comment: I updated the question with GPU information.

Comment: That's for the display driver, what about the keyboard / mouse issue?

Comment: Please try resetting your BIOS settings. If you're using any sort of USB hub for your keyboard and mouse please try connecting them to your USB ports directly.

Comment: I reset my bios few days ago (removed the battery for a few minutes) : Keyboard and mouse are not connected through a USB Hub but to the ports on the motherboard directly.

Comment: Your BIOS is really old, please install the latest one: https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/PRIME/PRIME-X470-PRO/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: I updated the BIOS to the latest version, but nothing seems to do the trick. I'm lost.

Comment: Could it be related to a broken / damaged USB stick? Does it makes sense that there's something broken, just at the beginning of the disk?

Comment: Unlikely it's caused by a bad USB stick. To be honest it's the first time ever I see a person for whom Linux doesn't detect USB keyboard/mouse.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
I have a wireless Xbox 360 adapter connected to the motherboard and that was causing the issue.

Apparently, Ubuntu is the only distro so far who's able to boot it.